# PHP - fgetcsv loop for get data from csv file column by column

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with 31 columns and 24 rows. I need with `fgetcsv` (or maybe another solution) to pass in the CSV and get data column by column. I have one solution:

```
 // { ?
  for ($col=1; $col<=32; $col++) {
    while ($data = fgetcsv($read, max, ";")) {          
      $row[] = $data[$col];
    }
    print_r($row);
    //... in the line behind i have sql query to insert data in base.   
  }  
  unset($row);  
}
```

The for loop is working but `$data[$col]` only gets data from the first column of the CSV, it doesn't get data from `$data[$col]` when `$col` is `2`, `3`, `4`, ..., `31`.

Where did I make a mistake, and what is the problem? The code looks okay to me, but I think that I don't know something about the `fgetcsv` function.

max is filesize of CSV, `fgetcsv` see that like max size of file. No matter what is in `fgetcsv` they see just first column, not loop every time when `$col` changes.

```
insert = "INSERT INTO xxxx (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,v16,v17,v18,v19,v20,v21,v22,v23,v24) VALUES ('$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]','$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]' '$row[9]','$row[10]','$row[11]','$row[12]','$row[13]','$row[14]','$row[15]','$row[16]','$row[17]','$row[18]','$row[19]','$row[20]','$row[21]','$row[22]','$row[23]','$row[24]')"
```

Comment: fgetcsv($read,max,";") - what is the value of max ?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: please post an example of the data.  you may use: `die('<pre>'.print_r($data, 1));` after the `while` brace open.

Comment: `fgetcsv($read, max, ";")` is this even legal? what is `max`?

Comment: fgetcsv fetches a row, not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
for ($col=1; $col<=32; $col++) {
  while ($data = fgetcsv($read, max, ";")) {
```

you are trying to fetch *all* rows from the file 32 times. The first iteration fetches all the rows from the file, since the `while` loop ends when `fgetcsv` returns `false` (when there is no more data to read).

> I need with `fgetcsv`(or maybe other solution) to pass in csv and get data column by column.

You can not read data column by column, since the file is read line by line, and the lines represent the table rows. If you want to iterate the table data by columns, you can read the entire table into an array, then exchange rows and cells:

```
$table = [];
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
  $table []= $row;
}

for ($r = 0; $r < count($table); $r++) {
  for ($c = 0; $c < count($table[$r]); $c++) {
    $new_table[$c][$r] = $table[$r][$c];
  }
}

// Use $new_table to iterate the table "by columns"
foreach ($new_table as $column) {
  foreach ($column as $cell) {
    $fields []= $cell;
  }
  $fields = implode(',', $cell);
  // do_something($fields)
}
```

---

So you don't need the outer loop iterating the column "indices", as `fgetcsv` already fetches an array for the next row where the items contain the cell values:

```
$row = fgetcsv($fp);
// $row = ['column 0 cell', 'column 1 cell', ... ]
```

At least, put the loop *into* the `while` loop that fetches the rows. If you want to iterate the cells, iterate the value returned by `fgetcsv`.

**Example**

```
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w+');

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 6; $j++) {
    $a[$i][$j] = "r $i c $j";
  }
  fputcsv($fp, $a[$i]);
}

rewind($fp);
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
  echo implode(' | ', $row), PHP_EOL;
  // Or iterate $row, if you need:
  // foreach ($row as $cell) { do_something($cell); }
}

fclose($fp);
```

*Output*

```
r 0 c 0 | r 0 c 1 | r 0 c 2 | r 0 c 3 | r 0 c 4 | r 0 c 5
r 1 c 0 | r 1 c 1 | r 1 c 2 | r 1 c 3 | r 1 c 4 | r 1 c 5
r 2 c 0 | r 2 c 1 | r 2 c 2 | r 2 c 3 | r 2 c 4 | r 2 c 5
r 3 c 0 | r 3 c 1 | r 3 c 2 | r 3 c 3 | r 3 c 4 | r 3 c 5
```

Comment: Me need to fetch first column with all rows of that column (without OTHERS column), in that loop need the array $row[]  containg data in row[1],row[2],row[3]...row[24] and put in base, and in the next iteration need to fetch again column num.2 with all rows, put in array $row[1],$row[2]... and put in base.

Comment: @MarkoAnastasijevic, you can't fetch column without fetching all the rows of the column. I have added a sample for this.

Comment: Ok. But in that case i dont know how to write sql query(insert) and insert data in base. In base i have 31 rows with 24 columns.  Problems is that because in your solution, i have 31 array (without numeration) all with 24 values with numeration.

Comment: @MarkoAnastasijevic, have you got the idea about exchanging rows and cells? I have added a sample loop gathering `$fields` and then joining them with `implode()`. You might pass the result of `implode()` into an SQL query (with proper escaping, of course!).

Comment: I try that solution, and loop is stuck in for ($r = 0; $r < count($table); $r++) {.... this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array push function as shown below:

```
$csvFile = fopen("somefile.csv", "r");

        $firstline = true;
        $column1_array = array();
        $column2_array = array();

        while (($data = fgetcsv($csvFile, 2000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            if (!$firstline) {

                if ($data['0'] != null || $data['0'] != "") {
                    array_push($column1_array, $data['0']);
                }
                if ($data['1'] != null || $data['1'] != "") {
                    array_push($column2_array, $data['1']);
                }
            }

            $firstline = false;
        }

        foreach ($column1_array as $value1) {

            foreach ($column2_array as $value2) {
                echo $value1 . $value2;
            }
        }

        // print_r($column1_array);
        // print_r($column2_array);

        fclose($csvFile);
```